# Conjugacy classes in alternating group

Tags: group-theory, symmetric-groups, fake-proofs

I am told that if $g \in A_n$ then its conjugacy class splits into two conjugacy classes of equal size if and only if the lengths in the cycle type of $g$ are distinct odd numbers.

Applying this to $A_5$, in $S_5$ we have 7 conjugacy classes with representatives

$1, (1 2), (1 2 3), (1 2 3 4), (1 2 3 4 5), (1 2)(3 4), (1 2)(3 4 5)$.

Taking the even ones we have $1, (1 2 3), (1 2 3 4 5), (1 2)(3 4)$ which have cycle types $(1), (3), (5) $ and $(2, 2)$. From what I said above it seems to say that $(1 2 3)$ and $(1 2 3 4 5)$ as they have cycles types $(3)$ and $(5)$ respectively which are odd. But this would give 6 conjugacy classes but there are only 5. What is my mistake?

Comment: Fixed points are also counted as cycles of length one. Since $(123)$ has $2$ fixed points and the $3$-cycle, it does not fall into the category of having cycles of distinct odd lenght, hence it does not split. On the other hand $(12345)$ has only one cycle of odd length (the $5$-cycle) and no fixed points, hence it splits. (Of course I mean their conjugacy class splits)

Comment: What do you mean by fixed points? Do you mean that the 4 and the 5 are fixed. So the cycle type is actually (3, 1, 1)?

Comment: Yes exactly, sorry for any confusion

Comment: I don't know what are you talking about, there are four even conjugacy classes, why do you say "But this would give 6 conjugacy classes but there are only 5."?

Comment: Sorry I am confused, $A_5$ has $4$ "candidate" conjugacy classes, and only one of them splits ($(12345)$ splits), so after it splits, it becomes $4+1=5$ conjugacy classes, do you mean this? @ThePhoenix